# How do I redirect users after logging in based on their role in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In my project, I want to have one table users and a role table to differentiate them with another role table.Can someone tell me how I can set that in my login controller?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

A good place to define this  is at the `LoginController`

Override the `redirectTo` function and return the proper URL based on authenticated user role

Something like this should work

```php
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return auth()->user()->role->name == 'admin' ? '/dashboard' : '/home';
}
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/authentication#included-authenticating)

I hope this helps